# Need an explanation : how to use AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I have a XML file containing some data, so I created a class representing it :

```
public class MyData
{
    ArrayList<SpecialData> list;
    int currentPage, totalPages;
}
```

As you can guess I have a list of `SpecialData` items, each one containing many fields, and `currentPage`/`totalPages` are two unique values in the XML file. I need to get and parse the XML file asynchronously, so I created this class :

```
class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, MyData>
{
    @Override
    protected MyData doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        MyData md = null;
        // Getting/parsing data
        return md;
    }
}
```

I gave it a try and the problem doesn't come from here because I correctly parse my XML file and my `MyData` object is perfect. But then I use this task like this in my main `Activity` class :

```
MyData md = null;
GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask(this);
task.execute(new String[]{url});
// How can this change my md object?
```

This may be very silly but I simply don't know how to link my `MyData` instance from my main class to the one that I get with `AsyncTask`. What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you declare MyData as a global variable and try to access it in `onPostExecute()` ?

Comment: It sounds like you might want a `Future<MyData>`.

Comment: You should be able to just do `task.execute(url)`, rather than `new String[]{url}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExecute` method:

```
protected void onPostExecute(MyData result) {
     md = result;
 }
```

Note that this assumes your AsyncTask is an inner class to your activity. If that isn't the case, you can pass in a reference to your Activity in the constructor to your AsyncTask. In those cases, you should be careful to use a `WeakReference` to your Activity to prevent resource leaks:

```
GetXMLTask(MyActivity activity)
{
    this.mActivity = new WeakReference<MyActivity>(activity);
}

protected void onPostExecute(MyData result)
{
     MyActivity activity = this.mActivity.get();
     if (activity == null) // Activity was destroyed due to orientation change, etc.
         return;
     activity.updateUiFromXml(result);
 }
```

Comment: So `md` is the field from my main activity?

Comment: @Rob - yes, `md` would be where you would want the result of your doInBackground to go. Of course, you'd probably want to either call a method in `MyActivity` to update the UI with the resulting `MyData` or do the UI updates directly in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: @ianhanniballake this is pretty dirty...breaks encapsulation.

Comment: @Tushar - I've updated my answer to call a method in MyActivity to properly encapsulate all of the functionality, rather than update a public/package default scope variable.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Hmm, I wasn't aware `get` blocked the UI thread. Given that, your solution is ideal. +1

Comment: It still doesn't work and I don't know why... My main `MyData` object is still `null` after the execution of the async task. I think I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what.

Comment: @Rob is it null after you use execute, or after it returns? It'll be null in the period between you calling `execute()` and `onPostExecute` being called.

Comment: After some debugging the problem seems a bit different, it's like I'm not entering my `doInBackground` method.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to implement a callback of some sort. This way you avoid exposing your data by making it publicly accessible, and you can implement other callbacks (such as an error callback if there is a problem loading the data).

For example, you could define an interface like this:

```
interface MyAsyncFinishedLister {
    void onFinished(MyData resultData);
}
```

Your AsyncTask will have an instance of MyAsyncFinishedListener, and you can call in onPostExecute as so:

```
protected void onPostExecute(MyData result) {
     myAsyncFinishedListener.onFinished(result);
}
```

Your main activity will implement this interface and look something like:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyAsyncFinishedListener {
    MyData md;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask(this);
        task.execute(new String[]{url});
        task.setOnFinishedListener(this);
    }

    onFinished(MyData result) {
        md = result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an AsyncTask to return a data object, you need to store it in a variable in class scope, not function scope.  To make this easy, the task is usually a private inner class.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `MyData` as a *variable visible to the whole class* and try to access it in **`onPostExecute()`** by assigning the result to the MyData variable.