# AsyncTask : what am I misunderstanding?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

My `activity` contains an inner `private class`, and that's basically how it looks like, with the problem :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    // My xmlData that I want to fill in the asynchronous task
    XMLData xmlData;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask(this);
        task.execute(url);

        if(xmlData == null) System.out.print("problem");
        // Prints "problem" : my xmlData is null, why?
    }

    private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
    {
        public GetXMLTask(Activity context)
        {
            // Constructor
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            // Here some stuff to get and parse my XML
            xmlData = new XMLData(list);
            System.out.print(xmlData.list.size());
            // this line shows that I correctly fill my xmlData object
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that after the call to the inner asynchronous class, my xmlData value is null and I don't why. I also tried this in my `GetXMLTask` :

```
MyActivity.this.xmlData = new XMLData(list);
```

Doesn't work though, why? What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: As far as I can see that shouldn't even compile, due to `new GetXMLTask(this)`. But fundamentally I think you're missing the meaning of asynchrony.

Comment: This compiles, but I didn't write the constructor because I just wanted to show the main things. I'll add it to avoid this, thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506244/need-an-explanation-how-to-use-asynctask

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The async task happens on a different thread.  The original thread continues immediately.  So the xmlData variable won't be updated until some unknown time in the future, it will not be ready immediately.

Comment: Don't use variables you expect to be filled in by an AsyncTask in the main thread.  Instead, process the results when the task is done, either in the doInBackground function or (if you need to alter the UI) the onPostExecute function of the AsyncTask.

Answer (score 4):

As Gabe pointed out in his answer, it won't be available until the task is done. For this reason you have `onPostExeccute()`. You pass the retrieved data from `doInBackground()` to `onPostExecute()` where you do what you need with the data or send it to a function in the main `Activity`

Answer (score 2):

Return the value in doInBackGround and catch it onPostExecute for the smooth execution without blocking the UI thread, there is also another way that you can call get() method on Asycn task object, but this will block your UI

Answer (score 1):

If creating the XML data takes considerable time you can first create an empty XMLData object, fill it in the background portion of the AsyncTask, and then continue your actions in the on Finish method. This way the loading will happen in the background thread, but you can perform the post load actions on the UI thread.